# Width of trapezoid at any height?

Tags: geometry

Assuming I have a trapezoid where I know the height, bases, and legs, I would like to obtain the width of this trapezoid at any height *y*. What I want is very similar to the median formula for a trapezoid, except that it needs to work for any height and not just 1/2 height.

For example, suppose I have a trapezoid with height = 10, short base = 10, long base = 20, left leg = 5, right leg = 5. If I want to find the width of the trapezoid at height *y = 3*, what formula could I use for such a thing?

Comment: You can construct a linear equation for the width of the trapezoid as a function of "height" measured from either base.  If you start from the long base and call that $ \ y = 0 \ $ , so that the width there is $ \ w = 20 \ $ , then the width tapers to $ \ w = 10 \ $ at the height $ \ y = 10 \ $ .  The width is decreasing at a rate of $ \ 1 \ $ for each unit of height, so the equation would be $ \ w \ = \ 20 \ - \  y \ $ .  If you started from the short base, you would have $ \  w \ = \ 10 \ + \ y \ $ .  The lengths of the slanted legs in a trapezoids must be equal, but don't enter into this.

Comment: This approach works for geometric figures with straight sides, so it also applies to triangles and trapeziums (the non-parallel sides being of different lengths).   BTW, in your example, I don't think the non-parallel sides can be 5 units long if the height of the trapezoid is 10.  But it doesn't matter for your question, since we don't use the "slant heights"  in the equation for width.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner: It would seem that your "trapezium" is my "trapezoid"; your "trapezoid," my "isosceles trapezoid."

Comment: @Amintire: As RR says, the trapezoid you describe is impossible, as the lengths of a trapezoid's legs cannot be less than its height, by Pythagorean Theorem.

Comment: @CameronBuie I just looked up the terms.  It's evident our usages diverge and I note that the words do not have universal meanings in English.  I learned "trapezoid" as the quadrilateral with two parallel sides and two non-parallel sides of equal length. I see some call a "trapezium" what I would have thought to be a general closed quadrilateral.  (It looks like I've picked up British usages, even though I'm not...)

Answer (score 1):

Say that the bases are of length $b_1,b_2$ (say with $b_1\le b_2$) and that the distance between them is $h$. Then at height (distance from the base of length $b_2$ in the direction directly toward the parallel line through the base of length $b_1$) $y$ we find the width by taking the weighted average of the two bases. In particular, for $0\le y\le h,$ we have the width at height $y$ given by $$w(y)=\frac{y}{h}b_1+\frac{h-y}{h}b_2.$$ It is readily observed by *looking* at a trapezoid that the width varies linearly with the height, and linear interpolation yields the formula above. As a side note, this formula also works for triangles, taking $b_1=0$ to be the measure of a sort of "one-point base."

Answer (score 0):

[scalene trapezoid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZ6cf.png)

If $CA \ = \ k \ CE$, $DB \ = \ k \ DF$, the formula should be $ EF= \frac 1 k  ((k-1)CD+AB)$. This formula doesn't use heigth $y$ but the ratio $k$.